# Knockout - multi-select lists on a dependentObservable (or computed)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a fiddle for this issue which has been annoying me for a few days now: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Quu4f/10/)

The pattern of including a selectedUserReport observable as well as a SelectedRecord dependentObservable is one I took from [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/View-Add-Edit-Delete-Design-Pattern)

The problem I have is that the PageModel.SelectedRecord function is evaluating whenever you click an item in the multi-select list, which prevents you from selecting any items.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any way you can simplify your fiddle down to the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a syntax error, here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Quu4f/11/)

```
selectedOptions: SelectedColumns //Shortcut, if prop is in context (it isn't right now)
selectedOptions: $parent.SelectedColumns //illegal
selectedOptions: $parent.SelectedColumns() //Correct
```

The issue is that when referencing an observable by itself, knockout allows you to drop the parens. However, anything else like an inline function or other reference, you need to the use parens. You were using the illegal line in the middle.

**Edit:**
Ok, so the saving is a bit of a mess to get into, but basically your save code was pushing data incorrectly. Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Quu4f/14/). Note, the edit line is now:

`self.selectedUserReport(new userReportModel(data));`

You weren't constructing a new model, you were just pushing the data. This has broken the dialog closing now, but the if you close it manually it will reopen the the selected options properly selecting. I hope you can manage it from here.

Comment: Doh! - Thanks for pointing that out - I still have an issue though in that the list doesn't show up previously selected columns - I've implmented the save functionality which clearly shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/Quu4f/13/

Comment: If you select an item in the multi-select and click save, you now get a new entry in the grid - re-selecting that entry - I'd expect the multi-select to show the previously selected value - it doesn't - it always defaults to empty - I'm guessing this is because the values in the SelectedColumns collection are not equivalent to those in the ReportColumnGroups collection as far as the control is concerned so it ignores them?

Comment: I shouldn't have added the save in like that - it's a distraction - in the real app - the save would ajax it back to the server, and then refresh the list from the server - the point here is that the UserReports data included at the top, contains a pre-selected column and I can't get that to display in the selection box. 

Anyway - thanks for all your help - I'll try simplifying the object graph so the multi-select only has to handle integers instead of objects and see where that gets me.

Comment: @BonyT Is there something else you need on this example? If not, would you mind marking this as accepted?

Comment: I need to work out why when you select the item in the list, the WatchType item isn't already highlighted in the list - what I can do though is open another question - the original one only talked about why the list was unusable.